# how to change number format in excel vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column H in an excel which has the value of following type

```
158.60
158.60
170.58
```

The number format is Number now I need to change this to like the following

```
158,60
158,60
170,58
```

I have the following code done but the result is showing weird...

```
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim lastRowk As Long
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")


lastRowk = ws1.Cells(Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row


For Each m In ws1.Range("H2:H" & lastRowk)

m.Value = "'" & m.Value


Next m



Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("H").Replace What:=".", Replacement:=",", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, MatchCase:=True


For Each m In ws1.Range("H2:H" & lastRowk)

If m.Value Like "*,*" Then


'Nothing

Else
m.Value = m.Value & ",00"

End If

Next m
```

am getting the result like this:

```
158,59742
158,59742
170,57936
```

But I want it like the following

```
158,59
158,59
170,57
```

Comment: What result do you get?

Comment: am getting a result like 1,58,59,742
1,58,59,742
1,70,57,936

Comment: `1` How is your cell formatted? `2` What is your Excel's local setings?

Comment: @SiddharthRout I have changed the query. can you please check it once...i think some string operations can resolve the issue

Comment: You haven't answered my question yet :)

Comment: do you really want to do this in VBA,   simple to do in the excel cells?

Comment: @SiddharthRout the cell is in number format

Comment: And answer to the 2nd question?

Answer (score 0):

Seing your final results,its not weird at all. It just looks like your initial value are  indeed numbers, but formated as ###9.99 so they are displayed to you with only 2 digits after the comma. However this is only the display, Excel keep the real values of your numbers which have apparently 5 digits.

One simple solution would be to round your decimal part to only 2 digits prior to make your stuff:

```
cell.value = round(cell.value,2)
```

Another solution, keeping what you already done, would be to round the 2 last digits at the end of your operations:

```
For Each m In ws1.Range("H2:H" & lastRowk)

  If m.Value Like "*,*" Then

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim strBefore As String
    Dim strAfter As String
    Dim dblTemp As Double
    Dim strTemp As String
    dim strDecimalSign as string 



    ' Change this according to the decimal sign on your system:
    strDecimalSign = ","
    ' or :
    ' strDecimalSign = "."


    ' get comma position
    i = InStr(m.value, ",")

    ' get the value before the comma
    strBefore = Left(m.value, i - 1)

    ' get the value after the comma
    strAfter = Mid(m.value, i + 1)
    ' make a temp double with 2 digits
    dblTemp = Round(CDbl("0" & strDecimalSign & strAfter), 2)
    ' Convert back to string
    strTemp = CStr(dblTemp)
    ' keep only the rounded 2 digits part
    strAfter = Replace(strTemp, "0" & strDecimalSign, "")

    'join all parts
    m.value = strBefore & "," & strAfter

  Else
    m.Value = m.Value & ",00"

  End If

Next m
```

(Written on my mobile so untested.)

And a third solution you might look into, is to change the decimalseparator format : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195207(v=office.15).aspx